# Angular - Filter array of object using multiple dropdown seleted

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to filter an array of objects using four fields of a form. All four fields are combinable.

The four fields are: 2 dropdowns with multiple selection and 2 text boxes.

When I click on a button I must filter the data based on the selected fields. This is the method I call when clicking the search button:

```
filterData(form: NgForm) {
    if (this.gridValueClone) {
      const filterType = form.value.selectedItemsType;
      const filterCompany = form.value.selectedItemsCompany;
      const filterDescription = form.value.description;
      const filterNameFile = form.value.nameFile;
      if (filterType.length > 0 || filterCompany.length > 0 || filterDescription || filterNameFile) {
        let search;
        let arrFilter = [];
        if (filterType.length > 0) {
          arrFilter.push({
            "field": "type",
            "value": filterType
          });
        }
        if (filterCompany.length > 0) {
          arrFilter.push({
            "field": "company",
            "value": filterCompany
          });
        }       
        if (filterDescription) {
          arrFilter.push({
            "field": "description",
            "value": filterDescription
          });
        }
        if (filterNameFile) {
          arrFilter.push({
            "field": "name",
            "value": filterNameFile
          });
        }
        const results = this.gridValueClone.filter(data=> {
          arrFilter.forEach(filter => {
              search = data[filter.field] === filter.value;
          });
          return search;
        });
        if (results) {
          this.reportsGridValue = results;
        } else {
          this.reportsGridValue = [];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As I have it, it works correctly with the filters of the text boxes (Description and File Name), you can select a box or combine them and filter well.

But I don't know how to incorporate the multiple selection filters (Type and Company), below I will put an example of the object that I obtain if I select all the filters by which the search should be done:

```
arrFilter = [
   {
      "field":"type",
      "value":[
         "Type1",
         "Type2",
         "Type3",
         "Type4"
      ]
   },
   {
      "field":"company",
      "value":[
         "CompanyA",
         "CompanyB"
      ]
   },
   {
      "field":"description",
      "value":"Prueba"
   },
   {
      "field":"name",
      "value":"Prueba.txt"
   }
]
```

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invoke the correct logic based on whether `filter.value` is an array or not.

This should work:

```
const results = this.gridValueClone.filter(data => 
    arrFilter.every(filter =>
        Array.isArray(filter.value)
            ? filter.value.includes(data[filter.field])
            : filter.value === data[filter.field]
    )
);
```

Your usage of `forEach()` in the filter callback is a little wonky so I got rid of that and replaced it with a call to [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: True, I forget to remove a "return", I have already updated it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. Still, `forEach()` is not the right method for that context. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Great, for it to work ok, I had to add a "{" just after the arrow function and to the Array.isArray block add the "return", thanks

Comment: It worked fine for me, but one of the dropdowns doesn't work well, although I'm reviewing it to introduce the pertinent adjustments.

Comment: I had a superfluous `}` leftover in the code, so I removed that. Shouldn't need the code block and return statement.

Comment: I was missing a setting in a field name and now everything works, your solution fits perfectly, I don't recall using "every" before :).